# How to set different color for dropdown arrow and under line in spinner?

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have spinner with dropdown arrow and under line and it's works well if I set same color for dropdown arrow and under line.

I set color with  `android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"`

Refer my code below

```
 <Spinner
                    android:id="@+id/spinnerPriority"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF" />
```

and selector

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item>
    <layer-list>
      <item
          android:left="-2dp"
          android:right="-2dp"
          android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
          <stroke
              android:width="1dp" />
        </shape>
      </item>
      <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" 
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down" />
      </item>
    </layer-list>
  </item>
</selector>
```

How I can set different color for dropdown arrow and under line in spinner?

Comment: inside your spinner tag use android:background="" to change the background of spinner you can use image, color, drawable etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this below code my friend it will help you

```
<layer-list>

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />
            <!-- background color of box -->
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:left="-2dp"
        android:right="-2dp"
        android:top="-2dp">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent" />

            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#ff00" />
            <!-- color of stroke -->
        </shape>
    </item>

    <item android:right="5dp">
        <bitmap android:gravity="center_vertical|right" android:src="@drawable/arrow" />

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Comment: thank you. but android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF" cnahge both colors.

Comment: than remove  android:backgroundTint="#FFFFFF"